# Generalization for a problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

Suppose there are $n$ horses and you can race at most $m$ horses at a time where $m<n$. You want to find $k$ horses such that they are the fastest among the group of $n$ where $k<m$ . What is the minimum number of races you need to have so that you can be sure of the result? Note (You to not have a watch) $$\text{Attempt}$$  Now in first case I assume that $n$ is divisible by $m$ and I can continue from here, but the problem is what if $n$ is not divisible by $m$. How to generalize it then? Also I don't know what 'not having a watch' implies. $$\text {Edit} $$ My assumption that for first case $\frac {n}{m}=j $ and continuing it from there was wrong. So my attempt for this question is zero. Can anyone suggest any other way?

Comment: Here are some lower bounds: if you are sure you have the k fastest horses then you must have races every horse and  so you need at least $1+\left\lceil\frac{(n-m)}{m-1}\right\rceil$ trials (one with the fastest $k$ and the rest to show that all the other horses are slower than the slowest of the fastest k). There are $\binom kn$ possible sets of the fastest $k$ horses and each race gives you $m!$ possible results (assuming you know nothing about the rest of the horses) so you need at least $\frac{\log\binom kn}{\log m!}$ trials (from an information theory viewpoint).

Comment: Can you show us how you solve this when $m$ divides $n$?

Comment: Also it isn't clear to me whether this question wants to know the minimum number of steps needed if you just want to be sure that your favourite $k$ horses are the fastest $k$ (in which case my first lower bound given above is the answer) or if you don't know anything about the horses ("you're shown to a field of $n$ horses you've never seen before") and need to determine which are the fastest $k$ in the optimal way (I have only given lower bounds for this)

Comment: Incidentally, I think "you do not have a watch" just means you cant time the races (since then you can just run each horse once, time them, and rank them once at the end).

Comment: @ Dan Robertson i thought we could use $\frac {n}{m}=j $ aNd do it but I was wrong. Ill edit my question soon. Can you suggest any way?

Comment: @user3658307 okay thanks got your point.